# Acees jquery function within plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know this question is asked couple of times and I searched many places but did not solved my problem.
I am using 1 jquery map plugin, it is working fine but I want to extend it a little bit, I want to call a function of this plugin defined in it.

```
(function($) {

var ABC = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.o = {
        source: 'locations.json',
        height: 420
    };

    self.init = function(el, params) {
        // variable and checks

        }
    var switchLevel = function(target, tooltip) {
        // checks
    }
}

    //  Create a jQuery plugin
$.fn.mapp = function(params) {
    var len = this.length;

    return this.each(function(index) {
        var me = $(this),
            key = 'mapp' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : ''),
            instance = (new ABC).init(me, params);

    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

When I am calling $('.myclass').mapp(); from html file it is working fine, but I want to call a function **switchLevel** in a external hmtl file.

I have tried different options like:

```
$.fn.mapp.switchLevel = function(myvalue){
   var newvar = (new ABC).switchLevel(myvalue);
};
```

Comment: you can not access that `var` without changing it to expose it within the original plugin function. This is a basic javascript closure/scope situation. That `var` is local to  the function it is contained in and can't be accessed outside that function

Comment: Yes you are right, this is the closure situation. But can you please tell me what I am missing or what should I change to access that variable.

Comment: Are you wanting to pass options into the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to pass option (level number) to the **switchLevel** function. Please tell me I am creating the plugin `$.fn.mapp.switchLevel` is correct way?